"Could not find" local declaration file written for an npm package
I have a TypeScript server running within a docker container that needs to use the NPM package "opsgenie-sdk". This package does not have any TypeScript types within the package, or available for download on NPM. The plan was to just write my own declaration files, but TypeScript refuses to read them, constantly giving the following error.
/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
server  |     return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
server  |            ^
server  | TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
server  | api/OpsGenie.ts(7,22): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'opsgenie-sdk'. '/opt/noc/node_modules/opsgenie-sdk/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
server  |   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/opsgenie-sdk` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'opsgenie-sdk';`
server  | 
server  |     at createTSError (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
server  |     at reportTSError (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
server  |     at getOutput (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
server  |     at Object.compile (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
server  |     at Module.m._compile (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
server  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
server  |     at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/opt/noc/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
server  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
server  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
server  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
server  |   diagnosticCodes: [ 7016 ]
server  | }

The file hierarchy is like this
server/
- api/
 - OpsGenie.ts
- typings/
 - opsgenie-sdk.d.ts
- index.ts
- tsconfig.json

This is the d ts I wrote
declare module 'opsgenie-sdk' {
    function configure (): unknown;
}

Here is my trimmed tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2021"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false                            
  }
    }

I've also tried moving the d.ts to the root folder, renaming it "globals.d.ts", using 'include' in tsconfig, which ended up being deprecated. Using 'typeRoots' in tsconfig, using 'paths' in tsconfig, none of these even changed the error that I was receiving.
I have verified that within the docker filesystem, the file layout is the exact same, and typescript has access to the exact same d.ts in the exact same location within the container.
